# Struts2 Jquery datepicker is not displayed

Tags: jquery, struts2, datepicker

Struts2 Jquery datepicker is not displayed. Only the text field is displayed.

In JSP:

```
<sj:datepicker id="fromdate" displayFormat="mm-dd-yy" minDate="%{new java.util.Date()}" showAnim="slideDown"  showButtonPanel="true" duration="fast" changeMonth="true" yearRange="2005:2020" changeYear="true" name="fromdate"/>
```

and I also included the

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%> and <sj:head />.
```

Even though date picker is not displayed. I'm using S2 2.2 jar with struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.1.jar.

In struts.xml file, I extends struts-default package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my JSP I already have **jquery** plugin (jquery-2.0.3.min.js). After removing this line now its working.

Comment: `jquery-2.0.3.min.js` is not the jquery plugin, is just the import of the jquery **library**. When you use the plugin,  the `<sj:head />` tag you've put in your page generates all the imports needed to run jquery (then the jquery library, the jquery CSS, etc...) Since you already had a jquery library import, you ended up with two colliding jquery imports. This is why after removing the manual import it works. When using the plugin, never import jquery libs by yourself

Comment: Thank you.. @  Andrea Ligios.